# More specific test to see where it is significant rather then whether it is significant at all? Degree courses against levels of motivation to study

Tags: spss, chi-squared-test

I've been doing chi-square tests to see whether there is a correlation between e.g. motivation levels when studying and degree course.  With chi-square, it only reveals whether there is a significant difference between degree course and motivation, but not *where* i.e. it looks like architects are significantly more motivated than politics students, but is there a significant difference between language students and psychology students?  Or between psychology and politics students etc.

[image: Percentages of motivation]

[image: Stats of motivation]

Which test would this require?  Would it be run for every combination of degree course pair?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Thanks I've been having trouble with ANOVAs though - the degree is nominal and I've put the motivation as scale, but it won't run an ANOVA as only one variable shows up.

Could you expand on what GLM is?  In the post hoc section I couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't SPSS provide options to analyze cross-tab residuals?  See http://www.helsinki.fi/~komulain/Tilastokirjat/09.%20Ristiintaulukko.pdf for instance.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!  Where is that from?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to assume that motivation is a continuous (scale) variable, run ONEWAY (Analyze > Compare Means > One-Way ANOVA) doing a post-hoc test on degree course or use the GLM equivalent for multiple factors.

Comment: Thanks I've added to the main question with a screen cap - having trouble with setting up a one-way ANOVA and GLM.

Comment: And just to clarify - doing a post hoc test (which one?) on degree will compare each degree to every of the seven other degrees and show whether each pair is significantly different from each other?  (That's what I'm hoping to do).